# Set the size of Positive Button in DialogFragment

Tags: android-dialogfragment

I have the following custom dialog extended from AppCompatDialogFragment:

```
public class MyDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment
  {
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    // inflate the actual dialog from XML ...

    builder.setPositiveButton( R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
        // ...
        }
      });

    // ...
    }
  }
```

This works as expected, with one caveat: the Positive Button is way too small on Tablets.

I'd like to customize its size. I am aware of the solution in case of AlertDialogs, which involves

```
Button btnPositive = alert.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
btnPositive.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE);
```

in the AlertDialog's onShow(); DialogFragments however seem to have no equivalent of the 'getButton()' method?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer 5 minutes after posting this question:

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
  {
  @Override
  public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
    Button btnPositive = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    btnPositive.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
    }
  });
```

i.e. simply cast the created() Dialog to AlertDialog. Sorry about that!